# regular expression in order to find emails that are not in a tag

Tags: php, regex, email

So I want to create a regex expression (in PHP) that can only find email addresses outside a tag value.

```
found@test.com
found@test.com found@test.com
<a href="mailto:notFound@test.com">found@test.com</a>
<meta name="email" content="notFound@test.com" />
```

When the email is inside `<...>` it should **not** be found. Because in this case it is maybe inside a href value, or something similar.
But all addresses that are not inside `<...>` tags should be found and later replaces with an font awesome @ instead of the normal one.

Currently I replace all emails without checking the `<...>`:
search: `/([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+)@([A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,64})/si`
replace with: `$1<i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i>$2`

But how can I use a negative lookahead in order to check, that there is a `>` on the left before a `<` and on the right side the other way around?

I tried to append `(?![^<]*>)` at the beginning and it seems to work. But what is the reverse for the end of the regex? And is this really the solution? I found it with try and error and I am not sure if this is save to use.

Here the test: https://regex101.com/r/lhqQiN/3

greetings and thanks for any help.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? One that supports `PCRE` ?

Comment: It will be used in PHP (sry, forgot to add this information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant way to solve your issue (when `PCRE` is supported, ie in `PHP`, `Python`, etc.), is to use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
<[^<>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S+@\S+
```

This says: **do** match anything between `<` and `>` and discard it afterwards. The alternative matches email adresses in a very simple format.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qUxqy1/1/).

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php
$regex = '~<[^<>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S+@\S+~';
$new_string = preg_replace($regex, '<font>$0</font>', $your_html_string_here);
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/pAKYyv).

Comment: greate, that helped me a lot. I changed the ending to `(\S+)@(\S+\.\S+)` in order to check for the dot and to get two groups that I can use to allocate `$1` and `$2` later. Perfekt, thank you :)